# Determine if a date is saturday or sunday using react

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

Can we determine if a date is saturday or sunday using react. If so, then how will it be implemented?

I have a table:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class HomePage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th colSpan="7">Nov</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th colSpan="7">Week 1</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td><td>21</td><td>22</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default HomePage;
```

I want to highlight the date which is saturday or sunday.
I am very new to react and I cant figure out how to do this.

Comment: I would suggest you to use a third party datepicker for this.You can use 
https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates

Answer (score 1):

This is not react specific. Construct a Date from the number and get it's [week day](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

```
function isWorkDay(date, month = 10, year = 2020) {
  const weekDay = new Date(year, month, date).getDay()
  return  weekDay !== 0 && weekDay !== 6; 
}
```

```js
function isWorkDay(date, month = 10, year = 2020) {
  const weekDay = new Date(year, month, date).getDay()
  return  weekDay !== 0 && weekDay !== 6; 
}

function DateCell({date}) {
  return <td className={isWorkDay(date) ? 'workday' : 'weekend'}>{date}</td>
}

class HomePage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main">
                <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th colSpan="7">Nov</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th colSpan="7">Week 1</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        {
                          [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22].map(date => <DateCell key={date} date={date} />)
                        }
                    </tr>
                 </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<HomePage />, document.querySelector('#app'))
```

```css
.weekend {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

Comment: I just have one small doubt. where in my react code should I place `function isWorkDay` and `function DateCell`

Comment: Anywhere you wan't to. I'd keep them private inside the file. Or you could have a separate file with date utils. Whatever this is up to your requirements.

Comment: can you please explain how I can keep these private inside the file

Comment: Just do not export them.